# C# empty property

Tags: c#, properties, is-empty

What's the preferred way to implement `IsEmpty` statement for your own container-like class?

*It could be a simple method `bool IsEmpty()` or you could have some gettable property `IsEmpty` / `Empty`.*

**I understand it's probably a matter a personal choice, but would you stick to properties or methods in such cases?**

Comment: what does container-like class mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general rule is if it is costly, or has side effects then make it a method. If it just reads a field make it a property.

Answer (score 2):

I will be use readonly property IsEmpty if it is simple accessor to private field if you have some algorithm to determine if something is empty you should use the method IsEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's definitely personal choice, and mine would be:

```
virtual bool IsEmpty() 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `IsEmpty` in VS 2008's help reveals 40 properties and 11 methods.  (Your mileage may vary, depending upon version.)  So either is acceptable, but property is more common.

The most important thing is to be consistent throughout your code.